# What was it like to be in first class on the R.M.S. Titanic?

Tags: titanic

I'm wondering what life was like on the Titanic? My Great-Great-grandparents went on Titanic. My family has many stories about it. I also have a diamond necklace that my Great-Great-grandma wore. They were in first-class. That's why this is very important to me.

I want to know more and to see if I can connect the stories together. I also have a photo of them at my house. I always look at it and wonder what it was like. I'm also looking for who their maid was because there is no record of her. I know that they had a maid because they never went on any trip without her. They had a "C" deck suite. I'll try to give lots of information so you can trace their maid. They were in their early 50s. I know that their valet died when the ship sank because it was either the maid or the valet. My family has lots of history and the more I know about the Titanic the more I can add to my family history.

Comment: *It was either the maid or the valet*... or perhaps one of the first class passengers :-|

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: There is a ton of info online, and my understanding is that even though the plot was schlocky, the movie was meticulous about the look of the interior, etc.  You can even get the full [floor plans online](https://www.encyclopedia-titanica.org/titanic-deckplans/c-deck.html)  As far as I can see, that link even has the names of passengers on C deck...

Comment: (But I think the question needs to be fleshed out a bit to be a descent fit.)

Comment: This is a question from a new user, who may not be familiar with our [culture](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/faq-historystack-exchange) on H:SE. Please make an extra effort to be welcoming: phrase feedback in a positive manner and try to explain our assumptions. If possible, offer constructive advice on how to [improve the question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224).

Comment: i'm upvoting this as its a good question from a newbie with some personal insight.The fact that the maid and valet were not recorded is interesting from a historical perspective. Note to @Lexus1234, no one here is likely to trace them for you. You are only likely to get pointers to things that might help *you* in your efforts.

Comment: The OP may be interested in [this upcoming game featuring a fully 3d realized Titanic interior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1AJkx3X2cM)

Answer (score 1):

That's difficult to describe: by the standards of the day, it was the ultimate in luxury. By our standards, not so much. Pretty primitive, actually. Also, compared with modern cruise ships somewhat small and cramped in overall size.

Allow me to explain: I was cruise-expert for a travel agency. As such, I did a lot of cruises on various cruise lines. Among them the [Rotterdam V](http://www.cruiseshipodyssey.com/ss-rotterdam-v-1959/), [Queen Elisabeth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth_2) and [the Big Red Boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Transvaal_Castle). All of them were pretty much dated. Cabins were (relatively) small, with pretty spartan accommodation and facilities. However, the passengers of the Titanic would have been amazed at the large size and amenities of the cabins.

That's because I could compare them with, for example, the [Rhapsody of the Seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapsody_of_the_Seas), or the [Queen Mary 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Mary_2). Those were (then) brand-new ships, with the latest of the latest in features and gadgets. Today there are even much bigger ships with more on board. *(Actually all cruise ships are currently laid up due to the covid pandemic.)* Some cruise ships have rock climbing walls on the chimney, and an ice skating rink with a [zamboni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_resurfacer). The QM2 had a planetarium, which I really liked.

Short story: your great-grandparents had the time of their life in first class. Until the accident, of course. The idea of having an indoor ice skating rink on board would have been ludicrous to them.

I'd like to add that the Titanic was an ocean liner, not a cruise ship. An ocean liner is designed to transport people on a scheduled service across oceans, in every season. Modern cruise ships are designed to entertain people as floating hotels. Speed is not an issue, and bad weather is avoided as much as possible.

Aforementioned Rotterdam V, QE2 and the Big Red Boat were all converted ocean liners. As far as I know, no ocean liners are in service today, except for the QM2 (sometimes).

The big difference is that your great-grandparents were travelling from A to B. The luxury was an extra, and to pass the time. The journey itself was not the destination. Compare it today with a first class train and the [Palace on Wheels](https://www.thepalaceonwheels.org/). The latter is not a form of transport, but a destination on its own.

Comment: This is a bit contradictory. First you compare with modern cruise ships, and then you add that actually that is not a fair comparison as it was an ocean liner with no modern equivalents.

Comment: @TomasBy: Back then there were no cruise ships. Today there are no ocean liners. "First class on a ship" is the common denominator.